# How to Correctly Model this Polymorphic Association?

Tags: domain-driven-design, polymorphic-associations, oop

Given the following Entities:

**Container**
**User**
**Client**
**Institution**

The Container entity has an association to one or more parties through the property AssignedToParties.

**Container.AssignedToParties** can contain a mix of Users, Clients, and Institutions.

What is the recommened domain model for this relationship.

I had considered the following options:

**1) Create separate properties for each type:**

Container.AssignedToUsers
Container.AssignedToClients
Container.AssignedToInstitutions

This seems pretty inelegant, but does not require business logic to check the types or do any downcasting.

**2) Create a common base class "Party" for User/Client/Institution**

Container.AssignedToParties would then be a collection of Party entities. This seems like an akward solution since the Party base class wouldn't have any methods or properties. I'm also not sure I like the idea of adding one more layer of inheritance here.

This solution, like #3, would require the system to check the types at runtime to make decisions and then downcast to either User/Client/Institution to process them.

**3) Create a Marker Interface IContainerAssignable that User/Client/Institution implement**

This would at least provide some type safety, but would require type checking and downcasting.

Right now, I'm leaning towards #3. It seems the simplest, but I've read in quit a few places that if your code is running logic that has to test for a given type and downcast that you probably have a bad design.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What do users, clients, and institutions have in common that make them want to share a container instead of existing in different containers?

Comment: The container doesn't contain Users/Clients/Institutions. It's a domain object that represents a list of assets such as files etc. The Users/Clients/Institutions are associated to the container to indicate their interest in them. You can think of them as "Watching" the container. Just an FYI, Client/User share a common base class Person. Institution is a really not a Person, and shares nothing with Client/User in terms of it's properties or behaviour except it's assignability to containers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment in response to my question, I would not have the assignment handled by the container at all.  To use your example, a file doesn't know or care who's watching it.

Instead, I'd either have the watcher implement some method (or collection property) to start watching a container (and in that case, making them an IContainerWatcher or the like would make sense), or else have that watching functionality offloaded entirely into a service that's dedicated to maintaining the associations, like a publish/subscribe mechanism does.  This is conceptually analogous to a many-to-many join table in a database schema.

Comment: I've simplified the example a bit to help focus the question. In our business, it IS important for a container to know who is watching it. The container is a very complex object with lots of behaviors that depend on who is "watching" it. It is also important to be able to travel the relationship between these entities going in the opposite direction i.e. see the containers associated to client/user/institution. Would IContainerWatcher be analagous to #3 (IContainerAssignable)? What is your opinion of using Marker classes?

Thanks!

Comment: Marker interfaces can be useful for declaring intents and such, i think they're fine.  That said, I'd try hard to see if there isn't some common behavior among them, even if that is a common method or event for use when the container changes (like the Observer pattern)